# Pasar una Cola(Queue) a un Archivo (Guardar y sobreescribir) C++

Tags: c++, archivo, codeblocks

El proyecto está en CodeBlocks, no sé mucho de programación pero quiero aprender más sobre c++ y su potencial que tiene.

#### `Cola.h`

```
#ifndef COLA_H_INCLUDED
#define COLA_H_INCLUDED
/*Practice No. 4: Queue */
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Cola {

private:
    class Nodo {
    public:
        T dato;
        Nodo* siguiente;
    };
    Nodo* nuevo;
    Nodo* inicio;
    Nodo* fin; //fondo
public:
    Cola();
    ~Cola();

    void insertar();
    int extraer();
    void imprimir();
    bool vacia();
};

/*************Constructor,destructor********/
template <typename T>
Cola<T>::Cola()
{
    inicio = NULL;
    fin = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
Cola<T>::~Cola()
{
    Nodo* recorrido = inicio;
    Nodo* bor;
    while (recorrido != NULL) {
        bor = recorrido;
        recorrido = recorrido->siguiente;
        delete bor;
    }
}

/*************Métodos (Funciones)***********/
template <typename T>
void Cola<T>::insertar()
{
    T x;

    nuevo = new Nodo();

    cout << "Dato a ingresar: ";
    getline(cin, x);
    getline(cin, x);
    //cin>>x;

    nuevo->dato = x;
    nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
    if (vacia()) {
        inicio = nuevo;
        fin = nuevo;
    }
    else {
        fin->siguiente = nuevo;
        fin = nuevo;
    }
}

template <typename T>
int Cola<T>::extraer()
{
    if (!vacia()) {
        string informacion = inicio->dato;
        Nodo* bor = inicio;
        if (inicio == fin) {
            inicio = NULL;
            fin = NULL;
        }
        else {
            inicio = inicio->siguiente;
        }
        cout << "Dato eliminado, ahora el dato a quitar  es:" << inicio->dato << endl;
        delete bor;
        //return informacion;
    }
    else {
        cout << endl
             << "Empty Queue!!!" << endl;
        //return -1;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Cola<T>::imprimir()
{
    Nodo* recorrido = inicio;
    cout << "Listado de todos los elementos de la cola." << endl;
    while (recorrido != NULL) {
        cout << "|" << recorrido->dato << "|"
             << "-";
        recorrido = recorrido->siguiente;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename T>
bool Cola<T>::vacia()
{
    if (inicio == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
#endif // COLA_H_INCLUDED
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cola.h"
#include "portada.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    portada();

    Cola<string> C;

    /************* Menu ***********/
    bool flag = false;
    char tecla;
    char answer[2];

    do {
        system("cls");
        cin.clear();

        cout << "\t***Queue:Elige una opcion***" << endl
             << "\t1)Insertar" << endl
             << "\t2)Quitar" << endl
             << "\t3)Mostrar Queue" << endl
             << "\t4)Salir" << endl;
        cin >> tecla;

        switch (tecla) {
        case '1':
            cout << endl
                 << "Opcion 1)Insertar<" << endl;
            C.insertar();
            system("pause");
            break;

        case '2':
            cout << endl
                 << "Opcion 2)Eliminar<" << endl;
            do {

                cout << "\aDesea quitar mas datos?? s/n: ";
                cin >> answer[2];
                if ((answer[2] == 'S') || (answer[2] == 's')) {
                    cout << endl;
                    C.extraer();
                    //delete C;
                }

            } while (answer[2] == 'S' || answer[2] == 's');

            system("pause");
            break;

        case '3':
            cout << endl
                 << "Opcion 3)to Show<" << endl;
            C.imprimir();
            system("pause");
            break;
        case '4':
            C.~Cola();
            cout << endl
                 << "\a\aHasta la vista baby :-3 " << endl;
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    } while (flag != true);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo que pretendes es volcar el contenido de la lista en un fichero? En ese caso... ¿Qué has intentado al respecto?

Comment: Exactamente, leí varios libros y entiendo que usan la biblioteca fstream en la que se puede usar istream y ostream ya sea para leer o guardar, pero en programas muy sencillos, cómo se podría implementar en éste tipo de programas? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No me queda muy claro lo que necesitas, pero entiendo que quieres que tu clase plantilla `Cola` pueda volcarse a un archivo:

> Pasar una Cola(Queue) a un Archivo (Guardar y sobreescribir)

Lo que no me queda claro es si quieres que esta funcionalidad pertenezca a `Cola` o una clase externa independiente se encargue de ello; así que optaré por la solución más flexible y la implementación corre de tu cuenta.

#### Escritura en archivo básica.

Para volcar contenido a un archivo deberás crear un `stream` de archivo (`fstream` o `f`ile`stream`) o un `stream` de salida de archivo (`ofstream` u `o`utput `f`ile`stream`); los `stream` disponen de un operador de inyección `operator <<` que permite inyectar datos con formato.

El siguiente ejemplo muestra cómo guardar un entero en un archivo usando un *stream de salida de archivo*:

```
std::ofstream salida("mi_archivo.txt");

if (salida.is_open())
{
    salida << 0xffffffffu;
}
```

El ejemplo anterior guarda el mayor número positivo representable por 32 bits en el archivo llamado `mi_archivo.txt`, si el archivo existía previamente lo sobre-escribirá, en caso contrario lo creará.

Si vamos al directorio de ejecución de nuestro programa, veremos que el archivo mencionado existe y su contenido sería:

> ```
> 4294967295
> ```

Que es, en efecto, el mayor número positivo representable por 32 bits, el cuál se ha guardado como una cadena de texto. Tal vez en lugar de sobre-escribir prefieras conservar el contenido anterior del archivo; eso deberás especificarlo en el momento de crear el `stream`:

```
std::ofstream salida("mi_archivo.txt", std::fstream f1("test.bin", std::ios::app);

if (salida.is_open())
{
    salida << 0xfabadau;
}
```

El código anterior abre `mi_archivo.txt` y situa el puntero de escritura al final del archivo, se consigue al pasarle como segundo parámetro `std::ios::app`, que significa `app`end (adjuntar).

De esta manera se conservan los datos que existiesen previamente. Al abrir el archivo veremos:

> ```
> 429496729516431834
> ```

Que básicamente es el valor 4.294.967.295 (`0xffffffffu`) y seguidamente el valor 16.431.834 (`0xfabadau`); si no supiéramos lo que hemos escrito veríamos un grupo de números sin sentido y aún sabiendo lo que hemos escrito no sabemos si es un número muy grande<sup>1</sup>, varios números encadenados o la combinación ganadora de la lotería del Sistema Solar, así que lo mejor será añadir un separador entre dato y dato:

```
std::ofstream salida("mi_archivo.txt", std::fstream f1("test.bin", std::ios::app);

if (salida.is_open())
{
    salida << ',' << 0xcafe5010u;
}
```

Con el código anterior, antes de escribir el número añadimos una coma para separar el nuevo dato de los datos anteriores, al abrir el archivo veríamos:

> ```
> 429496729516431834,3405664272
> ```

Después de la coma se muestra el valor 3.405.664.272 (`0xcafe5010u`).

#### Escritura en archivo avanzada.

Otra forma de escribir datos en un archivo es usar el modo binario en lugar del modo de texto:

```
std::ofstream salida("mi_archivo.txt", std::ios::binary);

if (salida.is_open())
{
    unsigned int ffffffffu = 0xffffffffu;
    salida.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&ffffffffu), sizeof(ffffffffu));
}
```

El segundo parámetro le indica al archivo que su modo de apertura será binario. La función de [escritura binaria](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) recibe un puntero a caracter (`char *`) y la cantidad de caracteres a escribir; por eso hemos necesitado [reinterpretar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) el dato a escribir para pasarlo a dicha función. La instrucción `write` del ejemplo está diciendo: *escribe binariamente en el archivo manejado por `salida` el contenido de lo apuntado por el primer parámetro hasta acanzar la cantidad de bytes indicada por el segundo parámetro*. Es posible que al abrir el archivo generado por el código anterior veas lo siguiente:

> ```
> ����
> ```

Lo cuál es bastante incomprensible, te aconsejo que bajes un [editor hexadecimal](https://www.google.es/search?q=editor+hexadecimal) para ver el contenido del archivo, que seguramente será algo así:

> ```
> FFFFFFFF
> ```

Se puede combinar la escritura binaria con la escritura al final del archivo:

```
std::ofstream salida("mi_archivo.txt", std::fstream f1("test.bin", std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);

if (salida.is_open())
{
    unsigned int fabadau = 0xfabadau;
    salida.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&fabadau), sizeof(fabadau));
}
```

El segundo parámetro es una combinación del modo de adjuntar y el modo binario. Al abrir el archivo con un editor exadecimal veremos

> ```
> FFFFFFFFFABADA00
> ```

O tal vez

> ```
> FFFFFFFF00DABAFA
> ```

Según la [*extremidad*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) del sistema en que ejecutes el programa.

Las ventajas de guardar en binario son:

- Puedes prescindir muchas veces de separadores: ya sabes lo que ocupa cada dato (todos los tipos de `int` ocupan 4 bytes, al menos en la misma arquitectura).
- Ocupa menos: la cadena `4294967295` ocupa 10 bytes, pero el mismo número en binario ocupa 4.

Las desventajas de guardar en binario son:

- No es legible por el ser humano: lo cuál dificulta interpretar o depurar el contenido.
- Su escritura y lectura es menos intuitiva: los métodos usados pueden ser más farragosos.
- El formato binario entre plataformas puede cambiar: la *extremidad* de datos y el tamaño de los tipos puede ser incompatible entre algunas plataformas.

#### Tienes otro problema.

Tu clase `Cola` es una plantilla que guarda datos arbitrarios de tipo `T`:

```
template <typename T>
class Cola {
    // ...
};
```

Los `stream` tienen capacidad de escrbir cualquier dato de tipo fundamental y el tipo `std::string` mediante el [operador de inyección](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), pero si el tipo `T` no es de los tipos que el operador acepta, entonces no podrás *inyectarlo* en el archivo a no ser que crees una sobrecarga del operador (tema que daría para otra pregunta) o definas unas rutinas diferentes de serialización (tema que daría para otra pregunta).

---

<sup>1</sup>Cuatrocientos veintinueve mil cuatrocientos noventa y seis billones setecientos veintinueve mil quinientos dieciséis millones cuatrocientos treinta y un mil ochocientos treinta y cuatro.

Answer (score 0):

Es igual de sencillo como el ejemplo que hayas visto, la única diferencia es que deberás crear una estructura de datos, ya sea utilizando un delimitador o un tamaño máximo del registro. (podrías utilizar la salida de imprimir como dato estructurado) eso es para guardar.

Y ya para leer es rehacer los nodos cuando veas el delimitador creas el dato. e iteras hasta el siguiente delimitador.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarías dos funciones, una para volcar, y otra para escribir. Puedes reutilizar la función `imprimir` para escribir, pero en vez de sin recibir parámetros, pasando el flujo donde quieres guardar datos:

```
void Cola<T>::imprimir(std::ostream& os)
{
  Nodo* recorrido = inicio;

  // cout << "Listado de todos los elementos de la cola." << endl;
  // La interacción con el usuario nunca dentro de las clases, siempre
  // fuera. En nuestro caso particular, para que las funciones de
  // lectura y escritura (esta función) sean equivalentes.

  while (recorrido != NULL) {
     os << "|" << recorrido->dato << "|"
          << "-";
     recorrido = recorrido->siguiente;
 }

 os << endl;
}
```

Fíjate que he sustituido `std::cout` por `os`. Esto es así porque `std::cout` es un objeto de tipo `std::ostream`. Puedes utilizar la función de esta manera:

```
Cola<T> c;
// ...
c.imprimir(std::cout); // Imprimir en la salida estándar
```

Pero también:

```
std::ofstream file("file_path");
Cola<T> c;
// ...
c.imprimir(file);
```

¿Por qué? Porque `std::ofstream` es una clase que hereda de `std::ostream`. En otras palabras, un objeto de tipo `std::ofstream`, es también de tipo `std::ostream`.

`std::ostream` es una especie de interfaz genérica para flujos de salida (objetos en los que puedes insertar datos), y hay dos clases que derivan de `std::ostream`: `std::ofstream` (ficheros) y `std::ostringstream` (tratar una cadena como un flujo). Tu función `imprimir(std::ostream&)` funciona para cualquier tipo de flujo de salida.

Para lectura:

```
void Cola<T>::leer(std::istream& is)
{
    T sig_elto;
    char saltar_char;

    while (is) {
        // Ignorar primer |, luego sacamos el elemento en sí,
        // y luego ignoramos el segundo | y el -
        is >> saltar_char >> sig_elto >> saltar_char >> saltar_char;
        insertar(sig_elto);
    }

}
```

Y ya puedes leer tanto de entrada estándar como de un fichero:

```
Cola<std::string> c1, c2;
c1.leer(std::cin);

std::ifstream file("cola_guardada.txt");
c2.leer(file);
```

Probablemente tengas que ajustar la función `leer` por esquivar posibles saltos de línea, por ejemplo.

Podrás imaginarte que `std::ifstream` también es de tipo `std::istream` (y que `std::cin` es un objeto global de tipo `std::istream`). Por analogía, para tratar una cadena como un flujo de entrada también tenemos `std::istringstream`.

Para fichero que sean ambos, lectura y escritura, tenemos `std::iostream` y sus versiones heredadas `std::fstream` y `std::stringstream`.